# Add fields/custom fields to page in the admin page (backend)

Tags: plugins, custom-field

following situation: let's assume I have page with some **ARTICLES** (textfields): Article1, Article2, Article3, etc..

Now is there a module for CraftCMS that I can add textfields (articles) to a page directly in the backend (admin page)? So when I want to add a new article, then I don't have to do this with PHP or else.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you're asking here. Have you tried creating "Fields" through the Settings page of the control panel?

Answer (score 1):

Craft CMS is a full-featured CMS. You should not need to use PHP at all unless you need very custom functionality.

It sounds like what you should do is create an "Articles" Section, and add whatever fields you need for articles into that section's layout. Then you'll have a nice user-friendly way to enter content on the backend.

Please see: [Sections and Entries](https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries)